# cannot debug a projet in vs2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, debugging

I have a very strange problem. I have an asp.net mvc application containing :

-my main project with my "home" controller calling a method "methodA" in my helper project
-a helper project containing my method "methodA"
-a "test" project with a test testing the method "methodA" of my helper project
-a "test2" project with a test also testing the methodA "method" of my helper project

The methodA is taking an input and return a boolean depending if the input is present in db.

That's the structure of my solution, now when I am debugging my app by calling my controller in my browser, I am able to debug my methodA (symbols are loaded and the breakpoint is fully red).
It's the same when I am debugging the test contained in my "test" project.

The strange problem, is that when I am debugging the test contained in my "test2" project, which is expected to pass by the "methodA", seems to not run this method (and returns me false in any case) :

When I try to debug this test, I have no build or run error, the only problem is that the breakpoint placed on my "methodA" is transparent and I have an indication on it "no symbols have been loaded for this document". The methodA placed in my test just returns me false (whatever the input, even if it's expected to return me true.)

I have clean and rebuild my solution, and also restart my computer.

My biggest surprise is that when I call this method from my main project or my first "test" project, I am able to debug this method, but when I call it from my second "test2" project, it's not executed and the function just return me false.

Answer (score 0):

Please got to main menu in Visual Studio:
TEST > Debug > All Tests

it will break during testing on your break points in test methods.

Cheers.